# How reliable is asus desktop raid?

Tags: raid, desktop

Does anyone have experience using the raid that comes with Asus desktop boards? Is it reliable? I have tried using it before but I had a less than reliable power supply and the computer kept rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

The RAID will probably be "fake raid" - ie software RAID acting as hardware RAID. It would be more reliable then no RAID, but will take the same performance hit as software RAID, but probably slightly less robust - especially in the case of a motherboard failure.

It's unlikely your rebooting issues were related to it's RAID.

If you can, use software RAID instead.